# Apache Giraph cannot run on CDH4.4.0

Tags: apache, hadoop, giraph

I try to run latest version of apache giraph examples, describe on the quickstart page (http://giraph.apache.org/quick_start.html).  I use CDH 4.4.0 (Cloudera distribution of Hadoop)
I have built Giraph with the dependecies updated to CDH 4.4.0. Everything went ok

When I run the examples I got following output

```
-bash-4.1$ hadoop jar /usr/local/giraph/giraph-examples/target/giraph-examples-1.1.0-     SNAPSHOT-for-hadoop-2.0.0-cdh4.4.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar 
    org.apache.giraph.GiraphRunner  
    org.apache.giraph.examples.SimpleShortestPathsComputation 
    -vif org.apache.giraph.io.formats.JsonLongDoubleFloatDoubleVertexInputFormat 
    -vip /user/hdfs/input/tiny_graph.txt 
    -vof org.apache.giraph.io.formats.IdWithValueTextOutputFormat 
    -op /user/hdfs/output/shortestpaths -w 1

13/10/02 18:31:58 INFO utils.ConfigurationUtils: No edge input format specified. Ensure your InputFormat does not require one.
13/10/02 18:31:58 INFO utils.ConfigurationUtils: No edge output format specified.    Ensure your OutputFormat does not require one.
13/10/02 18:31:58 INFO job.GiraphJob: run: Since checkpointing is disabled (default), do not allow any task retries (setting mapred.map.max.attempts = 0, old value = 4)
13/10/02 18:31:58 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
13/10/02 18:32:00 INFO job.GiraphJob: run: Tracking URL: http://hadoop57:50030/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201310021452_0015
13/10/02 18:32:22 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201310021452_0015
13/10/02 18:32:22 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201310021452_0015
13/10/02 18:32:22 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 6
13/10/02 18:32:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Job Counters
13/10/02 18:32:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Failed map tasks=1
13/10/02 18:32:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched map tasks=2
13/10/02 18:32:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=29054
13/10/02 18:32:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
13/10/02 18:32:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all maps waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
13/10/02 18:32:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all reduces waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
```

and the job log shows exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: run: Caught an unrecoverable exception     
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File 
_bsp/_defaultZkManagerDir/job_201310021452_0015/_zkServer does not exist.
        at org.apache.giraph.graph.GraphMapper.run(GraphMapper.java:101)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:672)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:330)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at 
org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File 
_bsp/_defaultZkManagerDir/job_201310021452_0015/_zkServer does not exist.
    at org.apache.giraph.zk.ZooKeeperManager.onlineZooKeeperServers(ZooKeeperManager.java:792)
    at org.apache.giraph.graph.GraphTaskManager.startZooKeeperManager(GraphTaskManager.java
```

The file `_bsp/_defaultZkManagerDir/job_201310021452_0015/_zkServer` sometimes gets created and sometimes not.

Could you please give any hints where to start hunting for this issue.

BR
Konrad

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Giraph is starting it's own zookeeper session. Just try passing the following as a VM argument to the GiraphRunner.

```
-Dgiraph.zkList=<zookeeper server address>:<port>
```

e.g.

```
-Dgiraph.zkList=localhost:2181
```

Your command will look something like this:

```
-bash-4.1$ hadoop jar /usr/local/giraph/giraph-examples/target/giraph-examples-1.1.0-     SNAPSHOT-for-hadoop-2.0.0-cdh4.4.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar 
org.apache.giraph.GiraphRunner  
org.apache.giraph.examples.SimpleShortestPathsComputation
-Dgiraph.zkList=localhost:2181 
-vif org.apache.giraph.io.formats.JsonLongDoubleFloatDoubleVertexInputFormat 
-vip /user/hdfs/input/tiny_graph.txt 
-vof org.apache.giraph.io.formats.IdWithValueTextOutputFormat 
-op /user/hdfs/output/shortestpaths -w 1
```

Best luck..!!